# Any chance javafuse can work?

Tags: java, fuse

I would like to build a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)-based underland filesystem application, in Java.
There are a few bindings library available on the web, [Fuse-J](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-j/), [jnetfs](https://launchpad.net/jnetfs/), [Fuseforjava](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuseforjava/), [javafuse](http://code.google.com/p/javafuse/).

None of them seem really alive as of today, so I gave my first try to `JavaFuse`.

The interface we must implement is there:
http://code.google.com/p/javafuse/source/browse/fs/JavaFS.java

and I wanted to reproduce this [fuse helloworld example](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/helloworld.html).

---

**Question:** Is there any chance that this:

```
static int hello_readdir(const char *path, void *buf, fuse_fill_dir_t filler,
                     off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
(void) offset;
(void) fi;

if(strcmp(path, "/") != 0)
    return -ENOENT;

filler(buf, ".", NULL, 0);
filler(buf, "..", NULL, 0);
filler(buf, hello_path + 1, NULL, 0);

return 0;
}
```

can be implemented by this java function:

```
public int readdir_pre(String path, long buf, long filler, int offset, Fuse_file_info info);
public int readdir_post(String path, long buf, long filler, int offset, Fuse_file_info info, int result);
```

- [Fuse_file_info](http://code.google.com/p/javafuse/source/browse/src/java/Fuse_file_info.java)

Maybe I missed something, but I can't see how to use `filler` to populate the directory content ...

There are other oddities just for this helloworld example, like:

```
public int read_post(String path, String buf, int size, int offset, Fuse_file_info info, int result);
```

which is supposed to *fill* `buf` with `size` bytes of data, whereas Java `String` are supposed to be immutable.

Comment: I would sugest using https://github.com/EtiennePerot/fuse-jna

Comment: yes, it looks interesting. But I already switched to [JNetFs](https://code.launchpad.net/jnetfs) which answered all my requirements so far! (although some bindings were still missing in the C library, I had to bind them myself)

Comment: +1 for having a list of FUSE-Java implementations.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [jnr-fuse](https://github.com/SerCeMan/jnr-fuse) project.

The project uses JNR, so you achieve full JNI performance and ease of implementation.

An example of implementation [hello-world filesystem](https://github.com/SerCeMan/jnr-fuse/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/serce/jnrfuse/examples/HelloFuse.java#L43) filter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure, what you are trying to do with the double function `read_pre` & `read_post`.

Though I guess, they represent pre-work and post-work. Maybe you can declare the normal `readdir()` and call you pre & post from inside? Passing the same arguments back & forth? Because you have to declare `readdir()` to the `fuse_main()`.

And about the second thing with buffers, it just expects a byte holding storage. You can pass it character arrays, or anything with bytes in it, denoted by `size_t size` that represents the size of buffer. In `helloworld.c`, the string characters are copied to buffer through `memcpy()`. You can read bytes from file and pass them on as buffer along with appropriate length.

I'm new to FUSE and would like to know how it is to work using Java as compared to the standard C.

Comment: you're certainly right in your guesses, but the result is the same, this `javafuse` library seem not to be usable at all ... the `memcpy()` function is not available in Java, and thus we have no way to provide the required information.