# Bad address exception when attempting to read a file under fuse-mounted directory

Tags: java, file-io, path, ioexception, fuse

I'm attemting to read a file under my mounted directory (with FUSE).

I use for that a Java Application that simply reads the content of a text file. This works under a normal file, but for a file under my mounted directory, it throws an exception as the following:

```
java.io.IOException: Bad address
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:242)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
```

What is the real problem? Is the path of the given file not appropriate?

Comment: which jdk are you using?

Comment: I don't know which one of these:
java-1.7.0-openjdk or java-7-openjdk

Comment: take a look at this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537066/implementing-writing-to-a-file-in-filesystem-using-fuse

Comment: the example didn't help me, there's no solution suggested

Comment: and this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233838/any-chance-javafuse-can-work they recomend jnetfs